# tmux: Detect which process runs in the active pane

Tags: linux, shell, process, tmux

Is there a way how to detect what process runs in the active pane?

[tmux: Find "my" window, check if it's active](https://superuser.com/questions/760406/tmux-find-my-window-check-if-its-active/760561) is related, however, it deals with the detection from within the pane.

I need to detect this from an external command (not from within the tmux session).

The problem most likely boils down to two steps:

1. Detect which pane is active
2. Detect what process runs in the given pane

Comment: You can find [my script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572139/52499) helpful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out tmux has powerful formatting capabilities for the list-panes command:

```
$ tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_active} #{pane_pid}'
0 4993
0 5382
1 6189
```

The command above will print

```
1 <process_pid>
```

for the active pane.

Fromatting options are described in `man tmux`:

```
 pane_active                     1 if active pane
 pane_pid                        PID of first process in pane
```

For the discussion of the term "first process in pane", see [What does the "first pid of a pane" in tmux mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/827176/what-does-the-first-pid-of-a-pane-in-tmux-mean)

Comment: Use `tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_active} #{pane_index} #{pane_pid}'` to also show the index of the pane, which you can get by pressing `<prefix>b`

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, the #2 problem can be resolved by

```sh
ps fut
```

It prints out all processes running in current tty (each pane should have unique tty)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is the name of the current process, try:

```
$ tmux display -p "${pane_current_command}"
```

However, that's not always correct, e.g. when the process was started from a shell script or by pressing `v` in less to invoke `$EDITOR`. In those cases, this works better

```
$ tmux run "ps -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}'" | tail -1
```

Of course you can grab additional details by changing the arguments to `ps`. Or you can replace `#{pane_tty}` with another tty.